# How to Show Notification before read data from server?

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing one application in that i have to send data and receive data from server.There is no problem to communicate with server to me.Here i want one requirement i.e,Before receiving data from server I want to show one notification in my app.I searched so many examples they are using Android Cloud to Device Messaging concept . I am unable to understand this, It is so difficult to me.please send any simple way for getting notification

Comment: have a look at this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @Durga Use GCM http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: What you want to show in notification. And you want to get notification from server or local notification?

Comment: i want to show notification when i received data from sever

Answer (score 0):

Simple code using :

```
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
    .setContentText("Subject")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "More", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent).build();
```

Can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html) with full example.

You need to seperate those 2 subject, adding/changing/removing notification is in your app wherever you decide it to be, get response from server won't show anything unless you'll handle it. for example, you want to upload file to your server, you'll init some notification with "Starting upload", once it complete (got OK from server) you will change to "Upload done" .

Comment: Thank you very much , but is it possible to use in my app my requirement is before receiving data from server ,display one notification

Comment: See my edit answer, the example i've provided to you doesn't call any server request.

Comment: if you any example regarding this please send me

Comment: I've already provided a link to a simple example, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html